# Unity : Objects become black when size is changed to smaller

Tags: unity, vuforia

While working with Unity 5.4, my models become black when I resize them to a smaller scale. When I make the models bigger they are fine. I am using a directional light . On the image below as you can see on the left the model is fine. But the others are black.

HOPE YOU CAN HELP.

[image]

Comment: Try Degrading your Unity Version (to Unity 4.6.1). This might be the bug in the new version.

Comment: I thought It was something to do with light . But as soon as I increase the size for the model. Its fine.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the objects, like what shader they are using with what material settings?

Answer (score 1):

Always try to scale your fbx kind of item outside unity. You may also encounter light mapping issue if you do that inside unity.For your current problem we need more info.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you for every thing. So what I did is resize the models until light was showing and used the model import setting tab to reduce the size scale from 1 to
something low like 0.6 resizing model but keeping it lit.